# Javascript Infinity Object

Tags: javascript, math, infinity

I'm caclulating the mean value of a function's request/sec, appearently the result number sometimes is too long so it displays as Infinity, is there a way to round it so it show a number only? Or make a sleep()/wait() while it's on Infinity?

well to be exactly, im monitoring req/sec on a graph, when it's infinity the line goes up not towards zero

Comment: You are most likely getting infinity due to the denominator being zero, not because the numerator is too high.

Comment: +1 It's hard to get to infinity with only additions, if you have "normal" numbers. And don't try to round infinity...

Comment: You should probably post some code, otherwise we're all just guessing here.

Comment: ...what jbabey said. Division by zero.

Comment: @jbabey: well to be exactly, im monitoring req/sec on a graph, when it's infinity the line goes up not towards zero.

Comment: @jbabey: yes it is? result is calculated and send to a chart, every thing is in code

Comment: "Rounding down infinity to a number" is one of the most awesome ideas I have seen in a while.

Comment: @nihulus What jbahey mean is that you should show the code here, not describe it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not too long to display. If you get Inf then you can't do anything with it other than know that it is something larger than the maximum possible value. This is the behavior of [IEEE floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) that are used in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the cause for this Infinity is a division by zero, not a big number.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely unintentionally dividing by zero.

```
var num = 1/0;
console.log(num);
//>Infinity
```

Conditionally check that the divisor is not null.

You can check the maximum value of an integer as follows:

```
console.log([Number.MAX_VALUE, Number.MIN_VALUE]);
//>[1.7976931348623157e+308, 5e-324]
```

See also the official [ECMA Description](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5) on Numbers