# Multiplication of same number in Java and Javascript giving different values

Tags: javascript, java

I have an expression which I am evaluating both in Java and JavaScript.

**Java**

```
System.out.println(582344008L * 719476260);

Output: 418982688909250080
```

**Javascript**

```
document.write(582344008 * 719476260)

Output: 418982688909250050
```

Why is there a difference in both values?

Comment: Numbers in Javascript are the equivalent of `double` in Java, not `long`.

Comment: Not sure why your example was so convoluted tbh

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/307200/1978785
582344008 * 719476260 is greater than Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript numbers are all IEEE 754 doubles, so it looks like there is some floating point error going on here. see [Difference between floats and ints in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179836/difference-between-floats-and-ints-in-javascript) for some more details

Comment: That makes sense. The result of `582344008.0 * 719476260.0` in Java is indeed `4.1898268890925005E17`, which is the same as the result reported for JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

### Preamble

As  **@Charlie Wallace** says

> 582344008 * 719476260 is greater than Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

**[What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin/307200#307200)

As **@baseballlover723** and **@RealSkeptic** say it's a [floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) error in precision/different storage type size [rounding error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error).

See [javascript types](https://javascript.info/types):

### What are the 7 primitive data types in JavaScript

There are 7 basic types in JavaScript.

- `number` for numbers of any kind: integer or floating-point. Integer/Decimal values up to 16 digits of precision. JavaScript numbers are all floating point, stored according to the IEEE 754 standard. That standard has several formats. JavaScript uses binary64 or double precision. As the former name indicates, numbers are stored in a binary format, in 64 bits.
- `string` for strings. A string may have one or more characters, there’s no separate single-character type.
- `boolean` for `true`/`false`.
- `null` for unknown values – a standalone type that has a single value `null`.
- `undefined` for unassigned values – a standalone type that has a single value `undefined`.
- `object` for more complex data structures.
- `symbol` for unique identifiers.

The `typeof` operator allows us to see which type is stored in a variable.

Two forms: `typeof x` or `typeof(x)`.

Returns a string with the name of the type, like `"string"`.

For `null` returns `"object"` – this is an error in the language, it’s not actually an object.

### What are the 8 primitive data types in Java?

```
    byte     for  8-bit signed integer  
    short    for 16-bit signed integer  
    int      for 32-bit signed integer  
    long     for 64-bit signed integer  
    char     for two bytes in Unicode  
    float    for *decimal* values up to  7 digits of precision   
    double   for *decimal* values up to 16 digits of precision (64 bits)  
    boolean  for true/false
```

*Decimal* values with a fractional component is called floating point. They can be expressed in either standard or scientific notation.

### Testing

A quick way to test is use an [online java compiler](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php) (Compile and Execute Java Online (JDK 1.8.0))

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Long Output: "+582344008L * 719476260L);
        System.out.println("Float Output: "+582344008.0 * 719476260.0);
     }
}
```

The command:

```
$javac HelloWorld.java
$java -Xmx128M -Xms16M HelloWorld
```

The Output:

```
Long Output: 418982688909250080  
Float Output: 4.1898268890925005E17
```

My desktop calculator goes to this:

```
4.189826889E17
```

and for [JavaScript online compiler](https://rextester.com/l/js_online_compiler):

```
//JavaScript-C24.2.0 (SpiderMonkey)
print("Output: "+582344008 * 719476260)
```

The Output:

```
Output: 418982688909250050
```