# Testing for "double" equality in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, numerical-stability

I have translated the experimental C# "float" version of [Clipper library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/polyclipping/) to javascript. In the newest sandbox version there is a function [IsAlmostEqual](https://sourceforge.net/p/polyclipping/code/HEAD/tree/sandbox/clipper.cs#l418) which seems to be hard to translate. Double equality cannot be compared using == operator due to numerical stability issues, so this function is needed to handle those issues.

`-9223372036854775808 - aInt` and `-9223372036854775808 - bInt` are easy to calculate using e.g. BigInteger library, but `BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits` is harder.

Any idea how to translate `IsAlmostEqual` function to javascript? Or specifically how to implement `BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits` to javascript?

```
private static bool IsAlmostEqual(double A, double B)
{
  //http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm

  Int64 aInt = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(A);
  if (aInt < 0) aInt = unchecked(-9223372036854775808 - aInt);
  Int64 bInt = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(B);
  if (bInt < 0) bInt = unchecked(-9223372036854775808 - bInt);
  return (Math.Abs(aInt - bInt) <= 10000000000);
}
```

Numerical stability and robustness:
http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm
http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~kettner/pub/nonrobust_cgta_06.pdf
http://cpc.cs.qub.ac.uk/MRSN/higham.pdf
http://www.2ality.com/2012/04/number-encoding.html

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using completely different function to test double equality from [here](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm). The original function uses signed int64 representation of double which is not possible in Javascript without using slow and complex bitwise operations or using some BigDecimal library. It uses a combination of relative and absolute error.

```
var IsAlmostEqual = function(a, b)
{
  if (a == b) return true;
  var diff = Math.abs(a - b);
  if (diff < 4.94065645841247E-320) return true;
  a = Math.abs(a);
  b = Math.abs(b);
  var smallest = (b < a) ? b : a;
  return diff < smallest * 1e-12;
}
```

According to my tests it seems reliable. Please test in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/OLIFOgoC/5/edit).

EDIT: I updated the code above. Now it produces the same result as with [ULP technique](http://jsbin.com/uxazIPeK/4) in all 83 test cases (using maxUpls 10,000). ULP technique is 8x-20x slower than above EPSILON technique due to Javascript lack of 64 bit integers.

Comment: Is it possible to have two numbers whose difference is less than `Number.MIN_VALUE`?

Comment: In http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm is said "A typical value for this backup maxAbsoluteError would be very small – FLT_MAX or less, depending on whether the platform supports subnormals." I assume that it should be FLT_MIN, not FLT_MAX. I don't think, Javascript supports subnormals, so I assume that the answer is no.

Comment: Please ignore the above comment of mine. The FLT_MIN is 5e-324. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MIN_VALUE says that values smaller than this are converted to 0. I cannot say yes or no anymore. And I'm not sure if Number.MIN_VALUE is the right value for maxAbsoluteError.

Comment: I would say `Number.EPSILON`, but it’s not the right one to use if your exponent is negative.

Comment: Number.EPSILON seems to be 2.220446049250313e-16, so it is more logical. Why negative exponent makes it unsuitable?

Comment: Because `Number.EPSILON / 10` (for example) is still a number; it’s just lower precision.

Comment: When I use Number.EPSILON instead of Number.MIN_VALUE, and compare 0 and Number.EPSILON/10, it reports wrongly false. But if I compare 1 and 1+Number.EPSILON/10, it reports correctly true. So Number.EPSILON seems not to be suitable. Any ideas?

Comment: `Math.abs(0 - Number.EPSILON / 10) < Number.EPSILON` is quite true… I’m not sure how you’d get `false` there.

Comment: I was calling a wrong function :(. It seems to work: http://jsbin.com/iNEKEJo/2/edit. I don't understand still why negative exponent makes it unsuitable? Could you test it. Add the values A and B in Javascript window.