# Strange result in simple math addition in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, addition

I have the following simple math operation.

```
var a = 1.12345678 + 1;
console.log(a);
```

which results in

```
2.1234567799999997
```

why?

I expect the result to be

```
2.12345678
```

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037839/avoiding-problems-with-javascripts-weird-decimal-calculations

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I would just recommend using `+a.toFixed(8)` JavaScript uses floating point precision, which is never 100% accurate

Comment: Not "never", only for those values it can't represent exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
Math.round(( OPERATION ) * 1e12) / 1e12
```

Supports all browsers. toFixed() causes strange things to happen on IE.