# Why does 0.14 * 100 return imprecise result in browsers?

Tags: javascript, math, browser

When I try `0.14 * 100` in browser console (result is same in all browsers), I get `14.000000000000002` as a result. If I, however, try `0.14 * 1000`, it correctly returns `140`.

If it returned approximate results in both cases, I'd just assume that 0.14 cannot be exactly represented in binary, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

EDIT: no, it is not duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004) - they use 0.1 + 0.2, which evaluates to imprecise number. Meanwhile, 0.14 is completely precise, the problem only occurs when multiplying it by 10 / 100, but it works with 1000.

EDIT: sorry, it's not precise, but the point stands - why does it return whole number when multiplied by 1000?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037839/avoiding-problems-with-javascripts-weird-decimal-calculations

Comment: Note that `0.14 = 2582544170319337226.24 * 2^-64`. Can you give us the binary representation of `0.14`? Hint: if the binary representation would be shorter than 64 letters, multiplying by 2^64 would yield an integer.

Answer (score -1):

0.14 cannot be represented precisely as a javascript float, so when you multiply by 100, the rounding error introduced by converting the string "0.14" to a float carries through to the result.