# Making a conditional statement based on floating numbers

Tags: javascript

I have some floating point number that i am obtaining. The number has strictly two decimal places and shall never be more than that.

I want to test if the number i have is a float and then make this two decisions.

1. If the number is equal to 5 but never greater than 5
2. If number is equal to 20 but never greater than 20 but never lesser than 5

I have this code

```
var get_sum = 4.45;

var dist = parseFloat(get_sum);

if(typeof(dist) == 'number' && dist == 5 || dist < 5){
          }
if(typeof(dist) == 'number' && dist == 20 || dist < 20 && dist > 5){
          }
```

Since i am dealing with floats me thinks `==` is a bad idea and i might get the wrong results.

Will my code always guarantee me correct results?.

Comment: `parseFloat` doesn't do anything if you already have a `number`, I believe

Comment: well, there is no other way i can check if its a float(without using es6) since technically its a double.

Comment: Javascript isn't Java, there's not really any such thing as integer vs double, everything numeric is just a `number`

Comment: Why do you check the type of `dist`? `parseFloat()` would only return `NaN` if `get_sum` cannot be parsed as a number but it is already a number - or is it a string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoiding problems with JavaScript's weird decimal calculations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037839/avoiding-problems-with-javascripts-weird-decimal-calculations)

Comment: I am obtaining it from local storage so some malicious user might change it to string and wreck the program.

Comment: They could also just change the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp):

> JavaScript Numbers are Always 64-bit Floating Point

So you can't really *test if the number i have is a float*, because every instance of a number in JavaScript is of the same type (the type `number`, related to the object [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)).

NB: parseFloat always returns a `number`, if it can't parse the float, it returns `NaN` (which is still a `number`), so your `typeof(dist) == 'number'` is useless ;)